# I want to make a GUI for a game coded in C for Linux Platform.Are there any API`s to do this or what woulb be the easiest way to make a gui

Tags: c, user-interface

I want to make a GUI for a game coded in C for Linux Platform.Are there any API`s to do this or what woulb be the easiest way to make a gui.

Answer (score 3):

SDL is best if you want to have a lot of action, with smooth animation, like [this](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/World_of_Goo) or [this game](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ProjectStarfighter.jpg/774px-ProjectStarfighter.jpg) . It is also very useful if your game is going to have [3D graphics](http://www.idevgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/06/homeworld.png).
[Here is a list of SDL games](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_games_using_SDL#List_of_games_using_SDL).
SDL gets its excellent 3D capabilities through OpenGL. SDL also has decent sound capabilities.

GTK and QT work best for games where smooth animated movement all the time is not a requirement. Games like [this](http://www.linux.com/var/uploads/Image/articles/122070-2.png). GTK & QT also works very well for games with [simple animations](https://taufanlubis.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/linux-game-pysol03.png) [like this](http://www.colinfahey.com/tetris/tetris_3d_gno3dtet_seb.jpg). A [huge list of GTK games](http://gtk-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=350x351x352x353x354&PHPSESSID=xpfyvhcukye).

However, to complicate things a bit, both [GTK](http://projects.gnome.org/gtkglext/) and [QT](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/opengl.html) have their own OpenGL extensions, which means you can develop fast-paced action games with those toolkits too.

There is also [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/) which does not even need X11, just a framebuffer, but still has hardware acceleration.

Update:
based on ninjaljs suggestion that the OP might want a toolkit for widgets inside a game, here is a [widget library](http://members.chello.nl/w.boeke/SDL-widgets/index.html) for use *within* SDL.

Comment: I think the OP wants a GUI library for games, i.e. something to use for in-game menus.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of game? There's several toolkits for normal GUI programming on X-windows. Check out gtk, Qt, wxWidget. If it's an action game meant to run outside of X or something, check out SDL.

Comment: @Abhi Define "simple" -- is this going to be simple in a sense like chess is simple, and could be emulated with normal UI widgets such as buttons, etc. A simple platform game would require more effort, and having to draw your game environment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A quick apt-cache search gives me libguichan and libparagui.